# How to Create a Custom sized Responsive Carousel Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm new to web Development and I'm trying to create a custom sized carousel beneath the nav bar on the right side of my website like it's in a section, but I don't know how and where to start. I've searched in so many forums but nothing that I want. If it's possible, please someone guide me with some clue. I appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/  This should help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the current code and structure of the site its hard to recommend a solution to the problem, however the bootstrap website has great documentation and examples you can use for almost all of its elements:

getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel

It doesn't appear that carousel has any kind of custom sizing options on the element itself, but maybe you could put some kind of card group and then nest the carousel inside of it?

Example of a card with nested carousel:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
<img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could then apply styling to the card or carousel to adjust the size.

Comment: Thank you so much . It was really helpful . It's good to know that you supportive people are here and having our back. I really appreciate that .Thank you again !!

Comment: Happy to help! :-)